# Get AMD 8320 CPU temp?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, amd

I'm looking to get the CPU temperature of my AMD FX-8320 chip. I have `lm-sensors` installed and I've run `sensors-detect` saying yes to all of the prompts. I also have the `kmod` system service running and when I do `sensors` I get a response with the data but I'm not sure how accurate it is. It contains negative temperatures in some places with max voltages lower than the minimum. Is there any other way to check the temperature of my CPU? Or is there anything I did wrong?

```
fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:       23.63 W  (crit = 125.02 W)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +16.8°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                   (crit = +90.0°C, hyst = +87.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

it8721-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +2.82 V  (min =  +2.05 V, max =  +2.75 V)  ALARM
in1:          +2.86 V  (min =  +2.99 V, max =  +1.67 V)  ALARM
in2:          +0.91 V  (min =  +2.76 V, max =  +1.43 V)  ALARM
+3.3V:        +3.34 V  (min =  +5.64 V, max =  +2.59 V)  ALARM
in4:          +1.93 V  (min =  +0.49 V, max =  +2.08 V)
in5:          +2.51 V  (min =  +2.46 V, max =  +0.65 V)  ALARM
in6:          +2.21 V  (min =  +1.70 V, max =  +2.88 V)
3VSB:         +3.14 V  (min =  +4.73 V, max =  +0.05 V)  ALARM
Vbat:         +3.41 V  
fan1:        4753 RPM  (min =   17 RPM)
fan2:         889 RPM  (min =   12 RPM)
fan3:         845 RPM  (min =   23 RPM)
temp1:        +36.0°C  (low  = -121.0°C, high = -95.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +39.0°C  (low  = +84.0°C, high = -65.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
temp3:       -128.0°C  (low  = -125.0°C, high = -84.0°C)  sensor = disabled
intrusion0:  OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Temperature-sensors are showing some temps wrong. 
I use FX8370E and I understand, that even in idle time it can not have proc. temp=9°C. How I understand it is wrong or it shows the temp of 1 core, but the summ of 8 cores are some time higher. I use thermal monitor applet in desktop and there are it8721 isa sensors, try select all that sensors in settings of thermal monitor applet and add as temp. applet in desktop as group of source, so you will see the highist temp of all that sources. Now for me it shows 31 C, so I can believe them and 9 C for 1 core (when I understood right). HDD temps and VGA temps it shows real, but SSD-temp shows always 100°C, it is unnormal. There are also -128 C, but I understood not, who injected in my PC case liquid nitrogen :) In your screen 16.8 °C can be the temp of 1 core of CPU. 52 °C can be VGA temp. 36°C can be motherboard temp and 39 can be CPU summary temp. -128 is wrong. And you need save your ears and change the CPU cooler, it is crazy helicopter, use 12 sm PWM cooler with good radiator and 2+ case-fans and all will be normal.

Comment: hmm...I have similar _observations_ with a intel i5, using a otherwise very good /sys interface. You know what: you should ask a Q, and somehow structurize. I have 4+1 /sys...hwmon sensors. They work very nice actually (I can tell by touching the case, if I follow for some minutes). But I'm just not sure if it 4x100% thermometer, the way it jumps up to 80 and down to 40 deg, Celsius. Q. of HW support (kernel/modules) and up-to-date packages.

Comment: "who injected in my PC case liquid nitrogen :)" THAT would be a nice title for a new Q; you really know how to hide a good punchline!